# Google Map API in React: How to assign InfoWindow for each Marker

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-react

I started my project with `create-react-app`, and installed `google-maps-react`.
Now I want to assign InfoWindow for **each** Marker, so I can show a lot of them at once. (maybe the answer is obvious, but not for me...)
My code:

```
export class MapContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Map
        className={'map'}
        google={this.props.google}
        zoom={13}
        initialCenter={{lat: 54.753986, lng: 24.670219}}
        style={nullStyle}
      >
        {this.props.places.map(place => (
          <Marker
            key={`marker-${place.name}`}
            title={place.title}
            name={place.name}
            position={place.position}
          />
        ))}
        {this.props.places.map(place => (
          <InfoWindow
            key={`infowindow-${place.name}`}
            marker={_JUST_BEFORE_CREATED_MARKER_}
            visible={true}>
            <div>{place.title}</div>
          </InfoWindow>
        ))}
      </Map>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To associate info window with a marker, render it inside a `<Marker>`, the below example demonstrates how to instantiate info window per every marker:

```
<GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={5}
    defaultCenter={new google.maps.LatLng(-25.0317893, 115.219989)}>

    {props.places.map(place => (
        <Marker
            key={`marker-${place.name}`}
            title={place.title}
            name={place.name}
            position={place.position}

        >
            <InfoWindow
                key={`infowindow-${place.name}`}
                visible={true}>
                <div>{place.title}</div>
            </InfoWindow>
        </Marker>
    ))}

</GoogleMap>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rzcmjy)

Comment: I already decided to change completely how I create markers (turned back to pure javascript) because I feel I have more control like this.  
But this makes much sense! One of those "Why I didn't think about that...". }:)  
Thank you, for your answer. }:)